# Класс для получения информации о браузере

Tags: php

Подскажите класс для получения подробной информации о клиенте. Хотелось бы получить в одном массиве от IP и OS до размера монитора.

Comment: А кто серверу скажет о размере монитора? Всё, что у него есть - это IP клиента, отправившего запрос и заголовки запроса вроде `User-agent`

Comment: @vp_arth да наверное с этим я перегнул ) Хотя у меня есть идеи на это...

Answer (score 0):

Информацию о размере окна получить не получится, как правильно отметил @vp_arth в комментарии - вы располагаете только IP-адресом пользователя и заголовками его запроса.

Для выжимки максимальной информации из user agent подойдет [этот проект](https://github.com/cbschuld/Browser.php) на гитхабе, ниже оптимальный способ получения IP:

```
function getIP() {
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
        $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    } elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
        $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    } else {
        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }
    return $ip;
}
```

Как правило этих данных хватает для комфортной работы